# Logback - same logger for two different levels

Tags: java, spring, logback, slf4j

I have configuring my logback-spring.xml file the following way:

```
    <logger name="com.mypack" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
     
    <logger name="TrackingLog" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
     
     
    <logger name="PostBackLog" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
     
    <root level="error" includeLocation="true">
       <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
       <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
```

I want also that level "trace" for com.mypack will behave the same way as "info". So far I didn't have any success with it. I need something like

```
    <logger name="com.mypack" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
     
    <logger name="com.mypack" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="TrackingLog" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
     
     
    <logger name="PostBackLog" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
     
    <root level="error" includeLocation="true">
       <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
       <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
```

appreciate for any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if conditions to set different logging level.

The first, You need to Janino library for conditional logging. Reference [janino](http://logback.qos.ch/setup.html#janino) and add this in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
  <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.6</version>
 </dependency>
```

The second, Add environment variable to set to different logging level.

For example

```
your_key=your_value
```

Finally, Add if conditions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.out</target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}:%-3relative][%thread] %-5level %logger{100} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    
    <!-- if exists your key in environment variable -->
    <if condition='isNull("your_key")'>
        <!-- if your key exists -->
        <then>
            <logger name="com.mypack" level='debug'>
                <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
            </logger>
        </then>
        <!-- if your key doesn't exist -->
        <else>
            <logger name="com.mypack" level='info'>
                <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
            </logger>
        </else>
    </if>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Daniel Braverman Please help to accept the my answer in case if someone have same problem